# Is it possible to create Responsive Web page using only media queries?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, media-queries

I'm trying to create a Responsive Web page with the only use of media queries but I could not...

I already added the following breakpoints...

```
@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {}

@media screen and (max-width:525px) {}
```

I got an error in the size of 360px...

please anyone can help me to solve this problem I don't know what is the exact problem

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. Overlooking some confusing language errors, i suspect you may be using a different definition for these terms than most of us.

Comment: you need to add some css inside...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to make a responsive page using media queries, you should define your queries for the resolutions instead;

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1400px) {}

@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {}

@media screen and (min-width:450px) {}
```

And try using a resizable screen to always check and also `width:auto;` for internal containers and `overflow:scroll` should help you do a nice work overall

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can create a responsive web page using media queries. You can use min-width or max-width but the best approach is the mobile-first architecture. Please add your source code to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: this code is particular one div 
@media screen and (max-width:525px) {
.leftsection h2 {
    align-items: center;
    padding: 18px;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
I got error in width there are some extra width was added ..